# Bijectivity in Complex planes

Tags: complex-numbers

Consider map $z \to w = f(z) =1/z$ and compute the image $f(D)$ of $D = \{z : |z - 1| < 1; |z - i| < 1\}$
Check if $f : D \to f(D)$ is a bijection.

[image]

Is there a general way to solve this type of problem?

Comment: When the range is specified to be $f(D)$, the function is automatically surjective. Therefore, you just have to prove the injectivity, which is not very difficult !

Comment: Note that invertible functions are bijections and that this function has an inverse, namely itself. This is true because $0 \notin D$.

Comment: What about Consider map
$z \to w = f(z) = \sqrt{z}; \sqrt1 = 1$; and compute the image f(D) of
$D = \{z : 1/\sqrt{3}  | Im(z) | < Re(z) < 1\} $  Check if $f : D \to f(D)$ is a bijection.